# Why I can't reshape my 1d array to 2d array in my code? Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a problem and I was hoping you can help me.
So I'm writing a code to calculate the shortest path length using networkx and numpy, so I create a function to do this,

```py
def costos(red, precios):
    pathlength = []

    for i in redes: #3d array with 100 2D arrays 
        graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
        pathlength.append(nx.shortest_path_length(graph, 0, 1, weight = 'weight'))
        y = np.array(pathlenght)
        z = np.shape(y)

    return y, z
```

and when I print the result I got the next output

```
[25, 10, 32, ..., 20] #A 1D array with 100 elements (shortest path length)
(100,) #Shape of the 1D array
```

What I want is to transform this 1D array with size of (100,) to a 2D array of size (10, 10), I know I can use `np.reshape` but when I add this to my function like this

```py
for i in redes: #3d array with 100 arrays
    graph = nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
    pathlength.append(nx.shortest_path_length(graph, 0, 1, weight = 'weight'))
    y = np.array(pathlenght)
    z = np.shape(y)
    w = np.reshape(y, (10,10))
```

I get the next Value Error

> cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (10,10)

What I'm doing wrong? I tried different things but nothing seems to work, so any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `pathlength` is probably a list of arrays. Which cannot  be reshaped

Comment: Pay closer attention to the indents.  You accumulate values in `pathlenght`, and (100,) shape `y` is the result of the **last** loop (the previous `y` values are thrown away).  In the 2nd case you try to `reshape` before `y` contains all 100 samples.  All of the `y,z,w` code should be **outside** of the `for` loop.

Comment: @hpaulj I see, yeah, it work now! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the fact, that I can't duplicate your error. I created my own output:
    import numpy as np

```
arr = np.arange(100)
print(arr.shape)
print(arr.dtype)
```

which return the size of:
    (100,)
    int64

And when I now use `np.reshape`, it works like that.

```
print(arr.reshape((10, 10)))
```

with the following output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
[20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
[30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39]
[40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49]
[50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59]
[60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69]
[70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79]
[80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
[90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]]
```

If that example doesn't help, please specify an example to replicate or at least specify the dtype of the array and the type of the produced data.